# How to plot a Bar graph when grouping on multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-science

Grouping data by date:

```
grouped = tickets.groupby(['date'])
size = grouped.size()
size
```

and then plot it using:

```
size.plot(kind='bar')
```

Result:
[image]

However,I need to group data by date and then subgroup on modeofcommunication, and then finally plot the count of each subgroup.

```
grouped = df.groupby([‘date’,’modeofcommunication'])
size = grouped.size()
size
```

Result looks like:

```
date                modeofcommunication
2019-03-15          Chat                       2
                    Internal Email             2
                    Phone                      4

2019-03-16          Chat                      25
                    Email                     20
                    Feedback Form              2
                    Phone                      6

2019-03-17          Chat                      23
                    Email                     68
                    Feedback Form             13
                    Internal Email             3


2019-03-18          Chat                    1822
                    Email                     57
                    Facebook                  14
                    Feedback Form             11
                    Internal Email            11
                    Phone                    812
                    Twitter                    4
```

How can I plot a bar graph for the grouped data such that the count of each subgroup(mode of communication) is represented as a vertical bar under the parent group?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame` from `MultiIndex Series`and then [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
size.unstack().plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
size.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezraeil. Both the solutions work very well, exactly what I was looking for.